# OpenMP: writing into std::map concurrently

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

i have a `std::map` with the key being identical to the thread_num. each thread is writing into the value, a `std::vector` here. hence it is guaranteed that each thread is only operating on "his" `std::vector`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>


int main(void) {

    std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int> > M;

// initialize map using first touch policy:
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1)
    for (int i=0; i<omp_get_num_procs(); ++i) {
#pragma omp critical
        M[omp_get_thread_num()] = std::vector<unsigned int>();
    }

// do some parallel operations:
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        M[omp_get_thread_num()].push_back(i);
    }

// disp the content:
    for (auto it_key : M) {
        std::cout << "thread " << it_key.first << " : {";
        for (auto it_vec : it_key.second) {
            std::cout << it_vec << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\b \b}" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the output looks as desired. the question would be whether the above code is legal? so i can  conclude that i can operate on a `std::map` in parallel, as long as i can guarantee that only one thread is operating on the secondary data of a specific key?

Comment: I don't understand your first loop, there's no point running it in parallel because the map will store everything in sorted order anyways.  Other than that your second loop looks legal to me.

Comment: @GuyGreer well, the first loop is maybe unnecessary complex. the idea is that the thread which operates on the vector should have created it  himself (ccNUMA locality, first-touch). importantly, the key's have to be initialized beforehand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second loop looks fine, since you are not modifying the map itself, but only value under the key.
From

[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/)

**Data races**
The container is accessed, and potentially modified.
The function accesses an element and returns a reference that can be used to modify its mapped value. **Concurrently accessing other elements is safe.**
If the function inserts a new element, concurrently iterating ranges in the container is not safe.

<strike>First loop probably better to do not concurrently, since it is minimal amount of work anyways - do it in one thread and syn_threads afterwards. The way it is now seems not safe by the standard, just happen to work on your configuration.</strike>

**EDIT**

Actually, since in first loop you are not accessing other elements but just inserting new ones, it is safe by the standard too, although there is no benefit of doing it concurrently.

Comment: @ Ilya Kobelevskiy: thanks. the critical issue is that the key's of the map are initialized non-concurrently (or using critical), because the key would be silently auto-initialized on first use. i did the initialization in a parallel region because the allocated memory is mapped to the domain of the core that touched it first (ccNUMA). But indeed, it is not necessary to do so.

Comment: @the_ducky Right, I overlooked that, first loop is not concurrent because of omp critical. It should work even without omp critical based on the reference to map docs through, since there is no access to other elements/iteration involved in that loop.

Comment: @ Ilya Kobelevskiy: Nope, it does NOT work when omitting the omp critical. Initializing the key's non-concurrently is absolutely necessary, because otherwise multiple threads may try to insert into the map at the same time. results in undefined behaviour and segfaults.